# BUG CONFIRMED: No performance data for VMXNET3 in ESXi 6.0?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, performance-monitoring, hypervisor

Did ESXi 6.0 completely removed the performance data for VMXNET3 or is there is a way, how can enable throughput logging/graphing for VMXNET3?

In ESXi 5.5 the ESXi client showed the network performance data just fine, in the 6.0 I see Network tab in VM Performance only for hw and nonVMXNET3 interfaces.

**UPDATE**
I see this problem on all servers upgraded with the last ESXi 6.0 release. I cannot do fresh install, but it should be well upgraded. All servers are 2012+ and contain the best possible server hw (Dell / SuperMicro / HP), hw network card, hw raids, mixed CPU types / vendors (Intel E5-xx v2 / AMD).

In VMware KB there is http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2119264 . The vClient do not show "No metrics Specified", but I think they somehow disabled VMXNET3 metrics in ESXi 6.0.

Can someone confirm me the same problem?

Is there is a way, how to get the statistics back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Did ESXi 6.0 completely removed the performance data for VMXNET3 or is
>   there is a way, how can enable throughput logging/graphing for
>   VMXNET3?

No, it's just there in vCenter - if you're not seeing you have an issue, you may need a reinstall.

EDIT - After playing around all day I have to apologise, you're absolutely correct, I don't know what I was thinking - it's clearly a major bug, and one I'll log with them. I've tried this just about every which way I can and you're absolutely correct.

EDIT 2 - I reported this to VMWare, they reproduced the error and have got a fix coming in 6.0U1 out mid-Sept.

EDIT 3 - It got patched and the patch is out as part of 6.0U1 - take a look at the 'Networking Issues' section of the release notes - http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/vsphere/60/vsphere-esxi-60u1-release-notes.html#rnetworkingissues

Comment: Can you post here a screen with ESXi version and network performance chart for VMXNET3? I just do a successful upgrade and the network performance option is missing for all linux VMs with VMXNET3 drivers.

Comment: Can you test it with no vCenter, just ESXi client? Can you test if you see network performance data for linux VM (best Debian 8) with VMXNET3 only (as I see hw adapters) network adapter?

Comment: Do you use the native tools or https://packages.debian.org/jessie/open-vm-tools or simillar? I am using the open-vm-tools.

Comment: Did you tried it with vSphere client?

Comment: Yep, it's broken in both, when I first responded I *thought* was on a v6 vCSA but it was a v5.5 which threw me, that worked fine but I wanted to be sure so built a small lab setup to prove it and you're right, it doesn't work - I've logged it with vmw though now.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation!

"I'll log with them", @Chopper3 - can you then post the link to bug report here, or if they do not have public bug tracking, their answer?

Comment: I will when it's formally logged as a bug, they're still testing it as I logged it quite late in the business day where I am (UK)

Comment: Do you have any update? I am user of ESXi free and I do not have any capability to report (only via forum).

Comment: No, though I know they're looking into it as I've had a few calls with the, I'll update here when I know something.

Comment: I accepted this as answer. Thank you for the reporting and edit here! Michael

Comment: No problem - glad I could help, we're a big vmw client so have their staff to hand all the time to ask, happy to help - good luck with 6.0U1!!